# Automatically add and delete images in WP7 app storage

Tags: c#, isolatedstorage, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I want to make a "recent pages" section in my WP7 app which will show thumbnails of 6 recent browsed pages. How to make a method which saves only 6 image files in the storage and when new ones come replace old ones with it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you define "new" based on the date/time that the image file in IsolatedStorage was created you could determine this by querying [`GetCreationTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.getcreationtime%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) on the file.

You can use [`IsolatedStorageFile.GetFileNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02ys433%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) to determine how many / which files exist. Note: you probably want to create these files in a specific folder so you don't have to worry about other files in IsolatedStorage.